# Django render different templates for two submit buttons in a form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I am a beginner at Django development, and I am trying to make a food diary application. After a user enters his email on `index.html`, another web page should be rendered according to whichever button he clicks.

I can possibly add two templates, but I also want my app to work if a user manually types a valid URL such as `/apps/<user_email>/addDiaryEntry/`. I don't know what to add in `/apps/urls.py`. Also, can I somehow access a user object's Id so my routing URL become `/apps/<user_id>/addDiaryEntry/` instead?

**/templates/apps/index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/apps/">
{% csrf_token %}

<label for="email_add">Email address</label>
<input id="email_add" type="text">

<button type="submit" name="add_entry">Add entry</button>
<button type="submit" name="see_history">See history</button>
```

**/apps/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        if 'add_entry' in request.POST:
            addDiaryEntry(request)
        elif 'see_history' in request.POST:
            seeHistory(request)

    return render(request, 'apps/index.html');

def addDiaryEntry(request):
    print ("Add entry")

def seeHistory(request):
    print ("See history")
```

**/apps/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Thank you for your help! Please feel free to share any best practices which I am not following.

Answer (score 0):

1) passing in an argument into a url, you can use regex groups to pass arguments. Here is an example using a kwarg:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_email>[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+)/addDiaryEntry/$', views.add_diary, name='add-diary-entry'),
```

2) just render a different template depending on which button was pressed:

```
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        if 'add_entry' in request.POST:
            addDiaryEntry(request)
            return render(request, 'apps/add_entry.html');

        elif 'see_history' in request.POST:
            seeHistory(request)
            return render(request, 'apps/see_history.html');
```

It's always tough starting out, make sure you put in the time to go over the docs, here are some places to look over regarding these topics:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/